# Apache process idling and eating memory

Tags: python, django, apache, memory

I'm stuck trying to debug an Apache process that keeps growing in memory size. I'm running Apache 2.4.6 with MPM Prefork on virtual Ubuntu host with 4GB of RAM, serving a Django app with mod_wsgi. The app is heavy with AJAX calls and Apache is getting between 300-1000 requests per minute. Here's what I'm seeing:

- As soon as I restart Apache, the first child process (with lowest PID) will keep growing its memory usage, reaching over a gig in 6 or 7 minutes. All the other Apache process will keep memory usage between 10MB-50MB per process.
- CPU usage for the troublesome process will fluctuate, sometimes dipping down very low, other times hovering at 20% or sometimes spiking higher.
- The troublesome process will run indefinitely until I restart Apache.
- I can see in my Django logs that the troublesome process is serving some requests to multiple remote IPs (I'm seeing reports of caught exceptions for URLs my app doesn't like, primarily).
- Apache error logs will often (but not always) show "IOError: failed to write data" for the PID, sometimes across multiple IPs.
- Apache access logs do *not* show any requests completed associated with this PID.
- Running strace on the PID gets no results other than 'restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>' even when I can see that PID mentioned in my app logs at a time when strace was running.

I've tried setting low values of MaxRequestsPerChild and MaxMemFree and neither has seemed to have any effect.

What could this be or how could I debug further? The fact that I see no output of strace makes me that my application has an infinite loop. If that were the case, how could I go about tracing the PID back to the code path it executed or the request that started the trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of restarting Apache, stop and start Apache. There is a known no-fix memory leak issue with Apache.

Also, consider using nginx and gunicorn—this setup is a lightweight, faster, and often recommended alternative to serving your django app, and static files.

## References:

[Performance](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Apache_vs_nginx#Performance)

[Memory Usage](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Web_Server_Performance_Comparison#Memory_Usage)

[Apache/Nginx Comparison](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/11/nginx-vs-apache/)